# Showing a space is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, quotient-spaces

I have the quotient space on $S^n$ (the n-sphere) given by the equivalence: $$x \sim y \iff x=y \text{ or }x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}=0$$ I can see that this essentially "draws" $S^{n-1}$  and then pulls that sphere to a point, splitting it into a bouquet of 2 n-spheres, joining at a point I have called $[s]$, the equivalence class of the "belt". I need to say whether this is a manifold or not, I say it is not as the space around $[s]$ doesn't look like $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't know how to formalise this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can remove the special point and check how many connected components you have.

Long answer: For $n\geq 2$, if you remove the special point you will disconnect the space. Any path from $(0,...,1)\to (0,...-1)$ must pass through the equator $x_{n+1}=0$. You can see this by projecting onto the last coordinate and applying intermediate value theorem. Removing a point from a manifold of dimension $n\geq 2$ does not disconnect the space so your quotient space is not a manifold of dimension $n\geq 2$ For many reasons, it is also not now a one dimensional manifold so it is not a manifold.

For $n=1$, removing a point from a one dimensional manifold locally disconnects the space into two components. However, in your quotient space, it will locally disconnect into four. More precisely, we can find a neighbourhood of the special point which is homeomorphic to the union of two open line segments which intersect at a single point. This space is not homeomorphic to an open line segment as it can be disconnected into four components by removing a single point.

Comment: Apologies if this seems like a trivial question, but why can we remove a point? My lecturer's notes on this are fairly bare and so I'm trying to piece together sections, we have that a manifold must be, (a) separated, (b) second countable, and (c) locally homeomorphic. What are we showing in this example?

Comment: So I am showing the quotient space is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am using the fact that if $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism then $f:X\backslash \{x\}\to Y\backslash \{f(x)\}$ is also a homeomorphism. 

In the $n\geq 2$, do you understand why removing a point does not disconnect an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I believe so, $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{p\}$ is path connected $\implies$ connected

Comment: Exactly. Any other questions?

Comment: Only one, why do we know that any neighbourhood containing $[p]$ becomes disconnected when $[p]$ is removed?

Answer (score 1):

Every open neighborhood of $[s]$ becomes disconnected after removing $[s]$.

Comment: Can you explain how? I'm thinking that in the case $S^2/\sim$ the "top sphere" with [s] removed is still connected, is this not a neighborhood? (a sphere with a pole identified)

Comment: By the definition of the quotient topology, any open neighborhood of [s] is the image of an open set in $S^2$ containing the whole equator. But such an open has to intersect both north and south hemispheres.

Comment: Still not sure I follow, surely the northern hemisphere (with the equator) and the southern hemisphere (with the equator) are both open subsets? Those don't intersect except for the equator

Comment: Actually, I think I understand, for a set to be open every point must be contained in a ball, so every point along the equator must be in a ball, that ball must be in both hemispheres, hence the set containing the equator must contain points from both hemispheres